# Individually throttled torrents with Python

Tags: python, bittorrent

I'm trying to write a python program that can handle seeding individually throttled torrents. Specifically, for some possibly large (up to 30 or so) simultaneously-running torrents, I would like to throttle the upload rate of each one to some individually-set values (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) in kb/s.

I have tried using rtorrent via xmlrpc, but there seems to be a bug that prevents non-global throttles from having any effect (in fact, checking the set rate for throttles always returns "0" regardless of what it was set to). Does anyone have any recommendations for libraries or other tools I can use from within python to control torrents with this level of granularity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well documented that you MUST set a global limit, since throttles share from that global bandwidth pool.

For the rest, https://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/RtXmlRpcExamples#Setting_and_checking_throttles